# Jolt specification needed for the below input and expected output

Tags: json, jolt

I need to split the `data` list into two separate `idExists` and `idNotExists` lists, based on whether `id` exists or not.

Can someone help me with Jolt Specification to achieve the below results?

Input:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "a",
      "id": "100"
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "id": "101"
    },
    {
      "name": "c"
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired Output:

```json
{
  "IdExists": [
    {
      "name": "a",
      "id": "100"
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "id": "101"
    }
  ],
  "IdNotExists": [
    {
      "name": "c"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried with the below spec but it is not working as expected

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "": {
          "id": "NotExist"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "": {
          "id": {
            "10*": {
              "@2": "IdExists[]"
            },
            "*": {
              "@2": "IdNotExists[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You are asking to solve your problem from A to Z. You should first try and only ask about specific issues you are encountering. Also please use normal formatting for your introductory text.

Comment: I have tried but not getting expected output

[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "id": "NotExist"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
   
        "*": {
          "id": {

            "10*": {
              "@2": "IdExists[]"
            },
            "*": {
              "@2": "IdNotExists[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Answer (score 1):

I had some modification on your spec, added **`*`** as it was missing in the selectors.

Modified shifting condition to ***NotExist*** and finally shift only name to the ***IdNotExists*** array.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "id": "NotExist"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "id": {
            "NotExist": {
              "@(2,name)": "IdNotExists[].name"
            },
            "*": {
              "@2": "IdExists[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: But with the above Jolt specification. we wont get below output        {
    "IdExists": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "id": "100"
        },
        {
            "name": "b"
        }
    ],
    "IdNotExists": [
        {
            "name": "c"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: as I have no idea how to filter I have added. But I dont need that default value which is added in response. "id":"NOTEXIST"

Comment: I am trying to understand, in IdExists why id is missing in the name : b.

Comment: NOTEXIST is an temporary value, added to identify the missing id values. It is removed in the shift spec `"id": {
            "NotExist": {
              "@(2,name)": "IdNotExists[].name"
            },
            "*": {
              "@2": "IdExists[]"
            }
          }` for the IdNotExists condition